# declare a value to a var based on user authentication

Tags: sql, security, authentication, parameters

I'm not really sure how to ask this,but...
I'm trying to figure out how to declare a value to a variable based on username and password.
for example: i have a sql database with user information including a security level. now when a user logs on to the website the server does the normal ins and outs, but then i want only certain users with certain security level to access certain pages.

so i need to declare that security level to a variable so when the secure pages loads it first checks to see if the user is allowed to access that page...

(i know we can do this by using roles and permissions but prefer to do it via code)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into Roles and Authorisation (as distinct from Authentication)

Comment: You need to define a set of roles and assign each users to a role (or roles) in the database. Once they have logged in (authenticated) you can test if they are in the required role before performing each action (authorisation).